# My python script is "freezing" when doing many calculations, and returns to "reality" when it has finished them...How can I fix this?

Tags: 22.04

My python code when is doing the calculations it prints a message that the program.py is not responding and when it finish the calculations and display the results, everything works. I mean the mouse, the buttons, no problem at all. How can I fix this temporary "freezing" while my python script is doing the calculations? I am running the python script on Ubuntu 22.04, installed on VMware player...

Comment: well, while it is doing calculations it isn't responding to input, so... This isn't necessarily a bad thing, it's fine. Anything you do to "fix" it will probably make the calculations be slower.